# Sort SharePoint List based on severity

Tags: sorting, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint custom list with issues listed as High, Medium and Low in one of the column of the list item called Risk.

Using a hidden field (IssueSeverity) 1 for  High, 2- Medium and 3-Low, currently I sort it ascending based on this IssueSeverity field to show High items first then medium and then Low items in a list.

Is there is any other better way to do sorting for this case? Please give your opinions or if you need any further information.

Comment: You have sorted it already? I don't understand what do you want.

Comment: Yes, Its sorted but with extra hidden field. I would like to know if there is anything Out-of-box available which I can leverage.

Comment: Now I see. I have an idea that you can do it by using SPD but it's out of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, your solution is best way for this case in terms of sharepoint standard reusable. Because sharepoint OOTB only give **sort** option just for several specific columns in order. Except if you want to use custom sharepoint feature using .net programatically.

Hope this help.